# How do proxy servers work?

Tags: networking, security, proxy

Recently I have read an article about proxy server and its usage.

The article says:

> "A proxy server can act as an intermediary between the user's computer and the Internet to prevent from attack and unexpected access."

- How can proxy server prevent my computer from attack and unexpected access?
- How do I come to know that my computer is under attack?

Just curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

A proxy is a bypass from your computer to the internet. In my business (Apprentice ICT Tech for a school), the proxy acts as a filter that filters websites ect. Your typical proxy will change your IP address, such as using a UK Netflix account and using a proxy/VPN to gain access to a USA Netflix account to watch their content.

Answer to Question1 - Proxy servers usually have firewalls on them, firewalls detect and stop incoming data, such as those of a DDoS/DoS. Also, having passwords to get into files/folders is a good idea to stop people who may just want to "look" at them, if somehow they get into the system.

Answer to Question2- Define under attack? If you have a good antivirus, your chance of getting a virus is small, same with FireWalls for your internet.

Please correct me if I am wrong, just applying what I have learnt last year when learning proxys.